# wrong data in Serial comunication Arduino-Raspberry with C and sysfs library

Tags: c, linux, arduino, raspberry-pi, sysfs

I'm trying to make Arduino and Raspberry comunicate. I have a C program on Raspberry that use sysfs library and an C-Arduino program.

What I do: The Arduino has already his own compiled (on the same Raspberry) program on board, than I compile the program on raspberry and I start it.

The problem: I get the data on Raspberry with a delay of one Raspberry input as you can see from the code below.

```
Type: a
OFFXX
Type: s
ONFXX
Type: a
OFFXX
Type: s
ONFXX
Type: s
OFFXX
Type: a
OFFXX
```

The first time I get always OFFXX

The arduino code:

```
int led = 13;
void setup() {                
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(57600);  
}
void loop() {
   if (Serial.available() > 0) {
      char comando = toLowerCase(Serial.read());
        if (comando == 'a') { 
           digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
           Serial.print("ON");        
        }
        else {
           digitalWrite(led, LOW);
           Serial.print("OFF");
        }        
   } 
}
```

and the raspberry code:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){

int fd = open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR);
if (fd == -1) {
  perror("/dev/ttyS0");
  return 1;
}

char msg[] = "a";
char rx[] = "XXXXX";

struct termios tios;
tcgetattr(fd, &tios);
// disable flow control and all that, and ignore break and parity errors
tios.c_iflag = IGNBRK | IGNPAR;
tios.c_oflag = 0;
tios.c_lflag = 0;
cfsetspeed(&tios, B57600);
tcsetattr(fd, TCSAFLUSH, &tios);

// the serial port has a brief glitch once we turn it on which generates a
// start bit; sleep for 1ms to let it settle
usleep(1000);

// output to serial port
while(1){
    printf("Type: ");
    scanf("%s", msg);
    write(fd, msg, strlen(msg));

    read(fd, rx, strlen(rx));
    printf("%s\n", rx);
}
}
```

I have this problem with both USB cable and GPIO

**EDIT:** The other issue: why the OUTPUT remember the last chars initialized before?

Comment: Can you comment on the LED status after each instruction ?

Comment: sure, the led works properly, if i type the 'a' the led switched ON if I type another key it is switched OFF

Comment: The message is probably stored in a read buffer in the Raspberry. I suppose you tried a wait loop between the write and the read ?

Comment: It's not a good solution for my purpose, however I just tried and I got Type: a [stopped with sleep for 2 seconds] OFFON was the result. Looks like if it has been chained

Comment: Yes, so you need to flush the input before you read it for the first time and then wait several ms to leave time for the Arduino to receive the message execute its part and send its message back.

Comment: Fflush doesn t work. How could I do?

Answer (score 0):

Open the serial port on Raspberry side in RAW mode. Use the following piece of code to open the port in RAW mode:

```
int fd = open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);

if(fd == -1)
{
        return -1;
}
else
{

        struct termios new_termios;
        struct termios orig_termios;

        tcgetattr(fd, &orig_termios);
        memcpy(&new_termios, &orig_termios, sizeof(new_termios));

        cfmakeraw(&new_termios);

        cfsetispeed(&new_termios, B57600);
        cfsetospeed(&new_termios, B57600);

        tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &new_termios);

}
```

Hopefully that would work perfect in your case.

Comment: There ia any difference, I have always the same problem.

Comment: cfmakeraw(&new_termios) function is not being used in the code you posted. This function sets the raw mode of serial port.

Comment: Yes, I saw. I mean I tried your code but I have always that problem

Comment: Instead of Arduino on other end, can you check by sending data to Docklight? This will confirm that the data you are sending from Raspberry is being sent correctly to other end.